# How do I Activate the Guest Account in Windows Server 2012 Essentials R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

I'm trying to activate the Guest account in Windows Server 2012 Essentials R2.  Everything I've read states that I should do it from the Users tab within Windows Server Essentials Dashboard.  The problem is, the Guest account is not listed under either Administrator (thank God) or Standard user.

My objective is to grant the Guest account full control over a share, so that anyone on my network can access that share anonymously.

This server is located in a home, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at your GPOs to make sure that the guest account is enabled?

[Guest account GPOs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852219(v=ws.11).aspx)

In other words, launch Group Policy Management, select a GPO or create a new one, and you'll find the option to enable guest account under

Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options

Comment: So in Group Policy Object I picked the existing Default Domain Controllers Policy at random.  The other was Default Domain Policy.  Those are the only two listed.  Then I drilled down to Accounts: Guest account status and changed it from Not Defined to Enabled.  Then I picked Default Domain Policy and drilled down through that to Accounts: Guest account status, expecting that it would now be Enabled, but it was set to Not Defined.  So these settings seem to affect only the selected GPO.  So your suggestion that I select one (presumably at random) or create one confuses me, as the ...

Comment: ... Accounts: Guest account status setting would seem to affect only the selected (or newly created) GPO.  Does Accounts: Guest account status need to be Enabled for a specific GPO?  If so, which one?

Comment: I wouldn't modify the default policies.  Instead, create a new policy object:  Start "Group Policy Management", expand your forest (on the left), right-click on "Group Policy Objects" and select New.  Give the new policy a name, then press OK.

Comment: The two policies are different, modifying one will not affect the other. To visualize this, click on each policy and look at "Links" in the right pane, you'll notice the 2 are different.  Links are targets where GPOs are applied, so you changed on GPO but not the other.

Comment: And to clarify the comment that was cut short: after you add the new policy, right-click to edit and make any changes there. When finished drag the policy from "Group Policy Objects" to your  forest (e.g., mydomain.local) to "enable" for machines in your forest.  Now machines in your forest will apply the policies as long as the security filtering shown for the policy allows it.  Wait 15mins and reboot the target machine for the GPO to take effect.  As a general word of caution, GPOs can be tricky and sometimes refuse to propagate and troubleshooting can be very long.